# cannot access rails request object in devise templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am setting `@application_url` in passwords_controller and getting its value as `nil` in `/app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb` template.
I am even unable to access rails `request` object directly in this template. I don't know whats wrong. Please help.

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController

  def create
    @application_url = request.host_with_port
    super
  end

end
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, you need to point the controller in routes file too with `devise_for`. Are you doing that? Also, add Rails.logger.info("Came here") in above to see if that line is logged and this method is actually being honored or not.

Comment: Already mapped my passwords_controller to devise passwords_controller, put a byebug in the create action it get stuck in there.

Comment: Can you show us the necessary server logs?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set routes file for devise and place a byebug or any logger statement in passwords_controller.rb to check if your customized passwords_controller.rb is being accessed.

```
devise_for :consumers, controllers: {passwords: "passwords"}
```

Comment: I am submitting the password reset form.

Comment: ok, sorry for the confusion. I got it now. Did you check if the create action is accessed by placing loggers ?